# For loop print sum of values from array only once, keeps repeating

Tags: java, arrays, sum, println

I am aiming to create a method which prints the total cost of all employees that are added to an array. 
Salary is added to the array using:

```
**Scanner sal = new Scanner(System.in);      
        System.out.println("Enter annual employee salary $");
        int salary = sal.nextInt();
        salaryArray[index] = salary;

        index++;**
```

I then use the following to get the sum:

```
  public static void cost()
  {
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < salaryArray.length; ++i)
    {
      System.out.println(sum += salaryArray[i]);
    }
  }
```

The problem is it prints out the result multiple times, I would like it to print only once, giving only one result. Further changes seem to break my code when I try to fix it.

Comment: What do you think `System.out.println` does? Why did you place it inside loop?

Comment: Your print statement is inside the loop. Why would it print only once?

Answer (score 1):

For each salary added you print the current sum.
You want to print the sum after the loop. So do that

As improvement, you could use a more meaningful name for the method as method names should generally start by an infinitive verb.
You could also use an [enhanced `for`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) as the index variable is only used to iterate every element.  The enhanced `for` provides it in a cleaner way.

```
 public static void displayCost()  {
    int sum = 0;    
    for (int salary : salaryArray){
      sum += salary;
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void cost()
  {
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < salaryArray.length; ++i)
    {
      sum += salaryArray[i];
    }
System.out.println(sum);

  }
```

Just show sum variable once .

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the result in a for loop, of course it would print multiple times. why not try this;

```
for(int i = 0; i < salaryArray.length; i++){
sum += salaryArray[i];//getting the value of the sum first
}
System.out.println(sum);
```